# Concatenate rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, r, concatenation

I have a dataframe structured like below:

```
Column A  Column B

1          A  
1          B  
1          C  
1          D  
2          B  
2          C  
2          D  
2          E
```

I want to concatenate all the rows belonging to a specific value in column A.

I want the final output to look something like this:

```
Column A Column B Column C  
1        A        ABCD    
1        B        ABCD  
1        C        ABCD  
1        D        ABCD  
2        B        BCDE  
2        C        BCDE  
2        D        BCDE  
2        E        BCDE
```

How would I perform this operation in R/ Python?

Thanks

Comment: `with(df, ave(ColumnB, ColumnA, FUN = function(i) paste(i, collapse = '')))` in base R

Comment: @Sotos are your sure about your solution?

Comment: @Tushar pretty sure. Why? Do you see something I missed?

Comment: @Sotos let me check, I might have missed something. Getting wierd warning message. `[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: a b c d e
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "abcd") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "bcde") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: Oh, convert to character and try again. You have factors that's why you get warnings

Comment: @Sotos Got it. While creating a `data.frame` ColumnB was treated as a factor, hence I got the error. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, we can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ColumnA', `paste` the contents of 'ColumnB' and create a new column with `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ColumnA) %>% 
     mutate(ColumnC = paste(ColumnB, collapse=""))
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   ColumnA [2]
#  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
#    <int>   <chr>   <chr>
#1       1       A    ABCD
#2       1       B    ABCD
#3       1       C    ABCD
#4       1       D    ABCD
#5       2       B    BCDE
#6       2       C    BCDE
#7       2       D    BCDE
#8       2       E    BCDE
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  ColumnC := paste(ColumnB, collapse=""), by = ColumnA]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ColumnB = c("A", 
 "B", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "E")), .Names = c("ColumnA", "ColumnB"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

---

If we need `python`, then

```
>>> import pandas as pd;
>>> df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> df1
#   ColumnA ColumnB
#1        1       A
#2        1       B
#3        1       C
#4        1       D
#5        2       B
#6        2       C
#7        2       D
#8        2       E
>>> df1['ColumnC'] = df1.groupby('ColumnA')['ColumnB'].transform(lambda x: ''.join(x))
>>> df1
#   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
#1        1       A    ABCD
#2        1       B    ABCD
#3        1       C    ABCD
#4        1       D    ABCD
#5        2       B    BCDE
#6        2       C    BCDE
#7        2       D    BCDE
#8        2       E    BCDE
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner in base `R` as suggested by @Sotos in the comment. Make sure that `ColumnB` of `df` is a `character` and not a `factor` for this solution.

```
with(df, ave(ColumnB, ColumnA, FUN = function(i) paste(i, collapse = '')))
```

Another base `R` solution:

```
df$ColumnC<-rep(unlist(by(df,INDICES = df$ColumnA,
function(t){paste(t$ColumnB,collapse = "")},simplify = F)),each=4)

>df
#ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
#1       1       a    abcd
#2       1       b    abcd
#3       1       c    abcd
#4       1       d    abcd
#5       2       b    bcde
#6       2       c    bcde
#7       2       d    bcde
#8       2       e    bcde
```

Comment: You can add mine in your solution as well If you like